# Windows shell API for status icons beside file icons

Tags: .net, vb.net, explorer, windows-shell

TortoiseSVN and Dropbox both have Windows shell extensions that make file icons within Windows Explorer show a small icon beside the main one, showing the file's status - has it been synced, etc

[image]

How can I make my application show icons beside files like that using the Windows API? Or is there some file attribute to do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, they have shell extensions, more specifically, icon overlay handlers, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123.aspx).